# Search for an ID in a text file (Turbo c)

Tags: c, turbo-c

I have this little homework:

> Given a text file, create a function that searches for a specific ID
>   provided by the user, inside the file. If it exists, print the entire
>   profile as follows:
>
> `ID_genre_name_age_height`

In the text file there is only one profile:

> `19800372_male_David_19_1.75`

So, my function should print that information if I input the same ID.

My code, which does not work so far is as follows:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
 int menu ();

main ()
{
int dato;
void create();
void Store();
void read();
void search();

clrscr();
   do
{
    dato=menu();
    switch (dato)
    {
        case 1:
            create();
            break;
        case 2:
            store();
            break;
        case 3:
            read();
            break;
        case 4:
            search();
            break;

        case 5:
            return -1;


        default: cout<<"\n Error";
             getch ();
             break;
      }

    }
    while (dato !=5);

    getch();
    return 0;

}

int menu ()
{
     int op;
     clrscr();
     cout<<"\n File creator system";
     cout<<"\n1 Create a file";
     cout<<"\n2 Store Information";
     cout<<"\n3 Read a file";
     cout<<"\n4 Search Information";
     cout<<"\n5 Exit...\n";
     cout<<"\n";
     cin>>op;

     return op;
}
.
.
.
.

  void search()
   {
    char ID[10],
    char ID1[10];
    char genre[10];
    char name[20];
    int age;
    float height;


 FILE *in;
 in=fopen("c:\\exercise.txt","r");

  clrscr();
  printf("Enter ID: ");
   fgets (ID1,10,stdin);

 do{
    fscanf(in,"%9s %s %s %d %4s",ID,genre,name,age,height);
  if (strcmpi(ID,ID1)==0)
   {
    printf("ID:%9s\n",ID);
    printf("Genre:%s\n",genre);
    printf("Name:%s\n",name);
    printf("Age:%d\n",age);
    printf("Height:%4s\n",height);
   }
  }while(!feof(in));
 fclose(in);


 getch();
 }
```

I can't figure out why it won't work, I input the ID, and it stays there.

Comment: @Jason - Please note: [The homework tag is obsolete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/179533). I'm rolling back.

Comment: The function `gets()` cannot be used safely. Please remove it from your program. Also it is no longer part of the C language (since the publication of the latest Standard in December 2011).

Comment: Off topic, still: Consider using a compiler different from Turbo-C. It is *very very* old, and probably not used in any serious project at all. Consider avoiding non-standard functions like `clrscr ()` and `getch ()` too.

Comment: @Arjun That's likely the toolset they're using at their college/school. For some reason, some of the so called 'educators' are quite fond of outdated (and often buggy) tools.

Comment: @Cubic - That would be unfortunate. user1730002 - If this is true, you should probably even consider talking to your teacher about using something more modern. GCC is awesome, free, and free of charge, for example. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if `fopen` succeeds.
2. If your input file has: `ID_genre_name_age_height` then this will be considered as a single string. Since you seem to to read them into variables, you should have your input file as a list of space-separated strings.
3. All your variables are char arrays but you use `%f` for some which is undefined behaviour. Change your variable types appropriately.
4. Check the return value of fscanf() to see there was no read error.
5. `feof` tells you whether you read past the input file, not the end of file. That means the loop will be executed one more time than you desired. Consider something like `fgets` then do a `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You fscanf conversions and types of variables do not match.

```
      fscanf(in, "%.0f %s %s %d %.2f", ced, sex, nombre, edad, altura);
```

`ced` should be `pointer to float`; it is `char[10]`; use `"%9s"` instead

`sex` and `nombre` are almost ok: there is danger of buffer overflow

`edad` should be `pointer to int`: it is undefined: define it and use the correct conversion

`altura` should be `pointer to float`: it is `char[5]`: use `"%4s"` instead

Answer (score 0):

Reread the docs for `fscanf`, you are using it incorrectly, check the return codes! You should have also been given a warning (or 9) by the compiler, if you don't have warnings on, then shame on you.

```
t.c: In function ‘search’:
t.c:13:5: warning: ‘gets’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
t.c:16:9: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat]
t.c:16:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
t.c:16:9: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat]
t.c:16:9: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
t.c:19:13: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
t.c:22:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
t.c:23:13: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
t.c:6:46: warning: unused variable ‘age’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: He uses Turbo C, which is likely to be a lot more liberal on enforcing the C standard (depending on the version of Turbo C he's using, the C standard might have not even been released at that point). gets certainly wasn't deprecated at the time (though using it still was a bad idea, but apparently less people knew about that).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm from venezuela, thats why part of the code Is in spanish, I forget to translate it, I'm using turbo c, bcuz thats what my teacher "uses" and he won't accept programs made In another compiler, such as dev c++, which I prefer. I'm currently making some changes to the code as stated here, I'll edit the main code so you guys can check it out.

Comment: user1730002 you can still use KingsIndian's response with most of my warnings to get a better picture of what is wrong with your code.